# Get the top selling product in Google Shopping

Tags: javascript, google-shopping-api

I've been looking everywhere just to get the Top Selling Product in [Google Shopping](http://www.google.com/shopping). I am aware that in their [homepage](http://www.google.com/shopping) there is this section "Popular this week", I really wanted to get that one via their API but I found none when doing my research.

Is there a way how to get Top Selling Product or Popular product this week in Google Shopping via API?

I am also thinking to scrape the HTML of their homepage, but it seems it is impossible to do because their homepage content is loading up through Ajax.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Research into using PhantomJS which is a headless browser. Then you can easily do DOM manipulations after you load the page.